# publish a new product or a new block on a certain date?

Tags: date, home

We need to publish a new product with some blocks on the home page on a certain date. can we do that with Magento? Any extension that would help it?

thanks

Comment: this extension will definitely help - Create a home page category and set dates against the products - https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-automated-product-publish-date.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have options in product editing to set

- Set Product as New to Date
- Set Product as New from Date

and in your block you just need to filter the items by those attributes and decide if you display or not.